# How to get text from a text box in JS

Tags: javascript

The following code does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="searchTxt"/>
    <input type="button" id="run"/>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#run").click(function(){
        var input = document.getElementById("searchTxt");
        alert(input);
        });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I get and print the value in the text box ?

Comment: since you are using JQuery you can this `document.getElementById("searchTxt");` with  `$("#searchTxt");`

Comment: It works fine on my end http://jsfiddle.net/vzrsnf3o/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the jQuery JS file inside your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW, for the newer version of jQuery, change the "src" url to: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

Answer (score 1):

.value on the element return by the getElementById function